# Windows Phone Equivalent of iOS UIAlertView?

Tags: windows-phone-7

There is a control on the Windows Phone that makes a message appear on the top of the page, usually to confirm a user's action. i can't find any infos if this is available for the developers to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you mean, but there's [`MessageBox.Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598690%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) if that's what you're looking for.

That lets you display either just an "OK" button or "OK" and "Cancel" buttons - and some text, of course.

Comment: yep ! that exactly what I had in mind ! I actually would prefer to display this and fade it out after a few second, like a notification. Do you think modifying a MessageBox is the right way to do this ? Or a Popup mayble ?

Comment: @Thomas: No, I think you should stick to the platform default way of doing things - that will give your users a consistent experience.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a dialog box that contains "OK", "Cancel" and perhaps another button, have a look at [Tomer Shamam's Windows Phone 7 Custom Message Box](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2010/10/19/windows-phone-7-custom-message-box.aspx). The [Kawagoe toolkit](http://kawagoe.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Controls.MessagePopup&referringTitle=Documentation) also contains a `MessagePopup` control. If you wish to use a popup box to show a message to the user, you can consider using [Shawn Wildermuth's approach of using a ChildWindow](http://wildermuth.com/2010/08/17/Using_ChildWindow_in_Windows_Phone_7_Projects).

Hope this helps.